# Как установить третий блок справа

Tags: html

Изучаю самостоятельно **html** и **CSS**. Не знаю как поднять нижний третий **div** вверх вправо.

```css
.header .container .header-left-first {
  width: 325px;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.header .container .header-left-second {
  width: 325px;
  min-height: 125px;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.header-right {
  width: 450px;
  min-height: 425px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-left-first bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="header-left-second bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer-left">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-right-first">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-right-second">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, хвалю `(изучать верстку самостоятельно )`... Во-вторых свойства `top right bottom и left` без `position: absolute | relative| fixed;` не будут работать, да и важно то, что абсолютным позиционированием блоки надо выставлять в исключительных случаях. В-третьих на дворе *21* век, как  прокомментировал Макс в ответе (удален) ниже, `float-ы` хороши для обтекания... Уже есть такие мощные инструменты как  `flex && grid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эту задачу можно решить без абсолютного позиционирования. Но для этого придется несколько изменить html-разметку (из вашего вопроса неясно, допустимо ли это). Нужно разделить container на два блока - левый и правый. Все остальное легко сделают флексы. Обратите внимание на [flexbox](https://html5book.ru/css3-flexbox/), эта группа свойств CSS вам еще не раз пригодится при решении задач по позиционированию объектов на странице.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.header .container .header-left-first {
  background: red;
  width: 325px;
  min-height: 300px;
}

.header .container .header-left-second {
  background: blue;
  width: 325px;
  min-height: 125px;
}

.header-right {
  background: green;
  width: 450px;
  min-height: 425px;
  margin-left: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container-left">
      <div class="header-left-first bc">
        <p></p>
      </div>
      <div class="header-left-second bc">
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer-left">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-right-first">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-right-second">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял можно через абсолютное позиционирование, так как у вас в нем есть `right: 0` добавить в `.header-right {position: absolute}`
а контейнер

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header .container .header-left-first {
  width: 325px;
  min-height: 300px;
  background: red
}

.header .container .header-left-second {
  width: 325px;
  min-height: 125px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  background: tomato
}

.header-right {
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 425px;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header-left-first bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="header-left-second bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right bc">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="footer-left">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-right-first">
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-right-second">
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```